# Find all files and folder have been changed or created in last 24 hours

Tags: files, find, date

I have modified some files present in various folders in my ftp server. This was development environment. Now I have to find all files and directories modified or created yesterday to migrate to productions.

Is there any way (Linux command) to list only those files and folders created or modified yesterday in my ftp root tree?

I want the command to return such address:

```
ftp://myfto.co/Virtual/YouWave
ftp://myfto.co/Virtual/YouWave/1.txt
ftp://myfto.co/Virtual/YouWave/2
ftp://myfto.co/Virtual/YouWave/2/readme.txt
ftp://myfto.co/Virtual/YouWave/2/install.exe
ftp://myfto.co/Android/Sample
ftp://myfto.co/Java/Sample2
```

Comment: Do you need to do this over FTP, or can you have access to the filesystem directly?

Answer (score 2):

To find files and directories which have been modified in the last 24 hours:

```
find path -daystart -mtime -1
```

The option `-mtime` uses the modified date. To look at the created date, use `-ctime`.

Comment: I think the OP was asking about how to combine -mtime and -ctime together (with an "or" relationship)

Comment: `-ctime` checks the status change time, not _creation time_ (whatever that is).

Answer (score 0):

To find files and directories modified OR created in the last 24 hours:

`find . \( -mtime -1 -or -ctime -1 \) -ls`

This solution uses the "or" operator to combine mtime and ctime results inclusively. The `\(` and `\)` are the brackets, escaped with `\` to group the OR components together. I added the `-ls` option to then list out those files so you could see the timestamp information

Comment: `-ctime` checks the _status change time_, not _creation time_ (whatever that is). `-Btime` (for birth time) is supported on some systems, not GNU/Linux yet.